# Range Partitioning for Creating a Table in BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to use integer range partitioning to create a table that will partition ascending with a field specified in the creation of the table. However, when I try to follow the guidelines of the documentation in specifying the field to partition appended data, the tested function gives me this error:

table.partitioning_type = bigquery.RangePartitioning(field='COUNTY_NUMBER')

[image]

If I take out the above code the function works. So, can I get some instruction on the proper way to use Range integer Partitioning for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For range partitioning you need more than defining just the field - you also need to define the range (regardless of what language you are using).

From the docs:

```
...
  "rangePartitioning": {
    "field": "customer_id",
    "range": {
      "end": "100",
      "interval": "10",
      "start": "0"
    }
  },
...
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions#api

So in Python it's not enough to provide `field`, you'll also need to provide an object with the `PartitionRange` for `range_`:

- https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.24.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RangePartitioning.html
- https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.24.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.PartitionRange.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.PartitionRange

---

For a full example, check the source code:

- https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/master/samples/create_table_range_partitioned.py

```py
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    table.range_partitioning = bigquery.RangePartitioning(
        # To use integer range partitioning, select a top-level REQUIRED /
        # NULLABLE column with INTEGER / INT64 data type.
        field="zipcode",
        range_=bigquery.PartitionRange(start=0, end=100000, interval=10),
    )
    table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
```

Comment: I did experiment with that parameter. However, I was having trouble getting it to work. Can you edit your answer so that it shows the python code with a range of 1 to 88 in intervals of 1?